# Python: plot data from a txt file

Tags: python

How do I plot a histogram of this kind of data,

```
10 apples
3 oranges
6 tomatoes
10 pears
```

from a text file?

thanks

Comment: Have a look at [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/index.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way you can assign different colors to the bars. It works with even a variable number of bars.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
import matplotlib.cm as cm

arr = np.genfromtxt('data', dtype=None)
n = len(arr)
centers = np.arange(n)
colors = cm.RdYlBu(np.linspace(0, 1, n))
pylab.bar(centers, arr['f0'], color=colors, align='center')
ax = pylab.gca()
ax.set_xticks(centers)
ax.set_xticklabels(arr['f1'], rotation=0)
pylab.show()
```

[image: bar chart]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can do this without having to handle the x-positioning (`sep`, `width`, `left`, `centers`).  In fact, you can simply use `range(n)` for `set_xticks()`, and use the `align='center'` parameter for `bar()`.

Comment: Glad you found the remark useful.  Here is another remark: it is easier to set `dtype=None` in `genfromtxt()`: the data types are correctly inferred; you also get, as a free bonus, a bullet-proof code against fruit names that are longer than 20 characters. :)

Comment: @EOL: Wow, I didn't know `dtype=None` behaved different than omitting `dtype`. That's nice to know. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, this surprised me too, when I checked the docs. :)  The default is `dtype=float` (purely numerical arrays).

Answer (score 2):

As the others suggest, Matplotlib is your friend. Something like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
indices = np.arange(4)
width = 0.5
plt.bar(indices, [10, 3, 6, 10], width=width)
plt.xticks(indices + width/2, ('Apples', 'Oranges', 'Tomatoes', 'Pears'))
plt.show()
```

will get you started. Loading the data from a textfile is straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Felix is right.

Matplotlib is one of the tolls available. Take a look, it has lot of examples. If you're not able to draw a histogram then you could ask another question and I'm sure there will be lots of people to help.

Here are some examples:
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html